# The text on the right side cannot be shown in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

```
    self.fm10 = tk.Frame(self.fm5)
    self.fm10.grid(row=3,rowspan=3,columnspan=3,padx=5,pady=5)
    
    self.treeview_box2 = Treeview(self.fm10,columns=('Assignment'))
    self.style2 = Style()
    self.style2.configure('Treeview',rowheight=70)

    self.treeview_box2.heading('#0',text='Date')
    self.treeview_box2.heading('Assignment',text='Assignment')
    
    self.treeview_box2.column('#0',width=60,stretch=False)
    self.treeview_box2.column('Assignment',width=175,stretch=False)


    self.treeview_box2.pack(expand=True,pady=5)

    my_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM schedule')
    self.schd = my_cursor.fetchall()
    print(self.schd) ##A138MS Excel Test
    self.count2 = 1
    for s in self.schd:
        self.treeview_box2.insert('',tk.END,text=s[0],values=(s[1]))
        self.count2 += 1
```

In this code, I am trying to show the value `s[1]` on the `treeview_box2` second column. The program is run successfully and stored into the database table. However the right side of value `s[1]` cannot be shown and only the left part is shown on the `treeview_box2` table. May I ask is there any problems causing the value can be printed out but only the right part cannot be shown on the table?

Comment: Note that `(s[1])` is not a `tuple`. Try `(s[1],)` instead.

Comment: It works after adding a comma thanks